# How can I develop a virtual drive

Tags: c++, windows, drive

I would like to create a virtual drive for windows. I'm not looking to map a drive or something like that, I'm looking to map it to my DLL functions or something of that sort.

How can I get this accomplished?

I read that I would have to develop a device driver, or a shell extension?
I have a lot of experience with C++ and C#. Where do I get started?

I want to make it as simple as possible at first, how much time do I think it would take me? And what's the simplest way to do it, so that I could build my prototype.

My motivation is to pipe a file into an application, that currently only reads files from the file system. I'm only interested in pumping 1 file, so I think that a whole virtual drive would be an overkill, as well as writing kernel mode code.

Comment: Look at StgCreateStorageEx().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to build it from scratch then yes, you have to build a driver. However, it would be much easier for you to use a proxy driver like [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/), and create the file system in user mode.

Take a look at the [Wikipedia article on IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installable_File_System), there are links to other useful tools at the bottom of the page.

Comment: What if I just wanted to implement a file and not a folder?

Comment: *not a drive , maybe a folder on an existing drive, without creating a drive.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Even if you have only one file on a CD for example, the root folder is still a folder.

Comment: Ah, so you want to inject a virtual file system object into an existing folder? Then you have to write a file system filter driver I guess.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best if you updated your question with your motivation, there might be a better way of accomplishing your goal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what it worth, and it's not open source, but I've found [this](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/). It's a ["fuse"](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) like for windows